# Publishing workflow to multiple site collections

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online

I have multiple site collections in SharePoint Online. All of those site collections uses the same site template and there is a list which uses a SharePoint Designer workflow. When we create/edit a workflow we have to publish the workflow to all of the site collections.

Can anyone tell me the best way to manage this?

Answer (score 0):

I would look to save the workflow as a template which generates a sandboxed solution that you can then upload to each of your site collections. Once uploaded, you would then just have to activate the corresponding workflow site feature.

I believe you can also include the custom workflow within a custom site template which you can then use to create the Site Collections you mentioned (which would save you a few steps)